# Disable normal behavior of Alt key

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, hook, keyboard-shortcuts

When pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, normally the focus goes to the window's menu. I need to disable it **globally**. Because my application works with <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. When the user presses some key in combination with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, my application sends another key to active application. So I just need to ignore <kbd>Alt</kbd> when it opens the menu.

I'm new to programming and I'm looking for VB.Net or C# code.

Comment: is it Windows Forms Application or WPF?

Comment: @imanabid Windows Forms Application

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
public void HandleKeyDown(object sender, keyEventArgs e)
{
  //do whatever you want with or without Alt
  
  if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

This should allow you to use Alt for whatever you want but keep it from activating the menustrip. Note that `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` also sets `e.Handled = true`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

Answer (score 2):

My first answer is to **NOT** use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for your program and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead. Blocking "normal" things from happening usually leads to pain in the future.

But if you must use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key I would check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12899915/231316) which uses message filters to try and intercept it at the application level.

If that doesn't do what you're looking for, you might need to look into Global hooks, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5861542/231316) will get you started down the path. Global hooks are generally considered evil so you should only use this if the above two suggestions don't work. You **must** make sure that you uninstall your hooks otherwise you might find that you need to reboot your computer often to fix weird keyboard problems.

Comment: Im making character auto correcting application. Work with such as notepad, WordPad applications. If I used Ctrl key for this, it may be confuse with Ctrl+A, Ctrl+B etc.
I think your fist suggestion helpful for me. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @JumRemdesk And in what way might ignoring Alt not cause problems with plain Alt, Alt+F, etc.? Also, standard question, what if two applications did this? What makes your application more special than the other application? Since you mention you don't actually do anything on plain Alt, I think you would probably be much better off with [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx), and let the end user customise the hotkey to use. But I'll assume you know your end user better than I do.

Comment: it will only ignore AltGr for menu. my application auto correct some character in local language not English. ex: when user press AltGr+B it will replace with 'ï' it's special char of my local language. user can't normally type it.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
    private class AltKeyFilter : IMessageFilter
    {
        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            return m.Msg == 0x0104 && ((int)m.LParam & 0x20000000) != 0;
        }
    }
```

And then you add the message filter like so:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new AltKeyFilter());
```