# how to prevent keydown e.alt from opening an irrelevant drop down menu?

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Shift)
        {
            PDiff = 20;
        }
        if (e.Control)
        {
            PDiff = 30;
        }
        if (e.Alt)
        {
            PDiff = 40; //opens up a drop down menu if not pressed first

        }
    }
```

ok so my program is 100% complete, but I'm having a glitch where half the time e.Alt does what I need it to do and the other half of the time it opens up an irrelevant drop down menu. The irrelevant drop down menu usually appears when I press shift or control before alt.

(The menu is Restore > Move > Size > Minimize > Maximize > Close btw)

I was told that changing the order of the code would help, but it either didn't work or I didn't understand what they meant.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090994/disable-normal-behavior-of-alt-key maybe

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you should set the `KeyEventArgs.Handled` boolean property to `true`. With that you can indicate that the default behavior should be omitted.

I'm not completely sure that it will solve this exact problem though, as I don't have the chance to test it currently.