# Prevent Alt key focusing Mainmenu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

If I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in a WPF application with a `<Menu>` element the first menu entry gets focused.
How can I prevent this behaviour.

My problem is that I have a [Scintilla.Net](https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) component with multiselect in my window, and when I try to select a rectangular selection (by holding down the Alt Key) my component looses the focus as soon as I let the Alt key go.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090994/disable-normal-behavior-of-alt-key) is a similiar question, but unfortunately it's about Windows Forms and not WPF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have that component, but it should work same as on `TextBox` for example.
Set the event handler on your `Window` for the `KeyDown` event:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
```

And check the key combination you want in codebehind:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.System && e.OriginalSource is TextBox)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

In your example it is important to check not the `Key.LeftAlt`, but `Key.System` and change the `OriginalSource` check from the `TextBox` to the type you want.

Comment: Thanks that worked. For reference: because the Scintilla component lives inside a WindowsFormsHost the WindowsFormsHost is supplied as OriginalSource.

Comment: Leaving a note for people finding this through google: If your goal is to prevent this from anywhere (not just a TextBox), you need to check for `if (e.Key == Key.System && e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt)`, otherwise things like Alt+F4 won't work anymore.